# Error occurred during deployment: Exception while deploying the app : UnsupportedClassVersionError

Tags: jakarta-ee, glassfish-4

```
                               An error has occurred
```

Error occurred during deployment: Exception while deploying the app [EnterpriseApplication1] : UnsupportedClassVersionError: Class mn.interactive.module.meta.dao.MetaDataDao has unsupported major or minor version numbers, which are greater than those found in the Java Runtime Environment version 1.7.0_02. Please see server.log for more details.

When upload EnterpriseApplication1.ear file into GlassFish Service.
How to solve this error?

Comment: possible duplicate of [java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12770622/java-lang-unsupportedclassversionerror)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are executing your GlassFish with 1.7.0_02 - but maybe you compiled it with a JDK 8?

You can execute older java classes in newer JREs, but not the other way round. So just install a recent JRE or explicitely start you GlassFish (or the IDE it is running in) with the JDK you use for compiling your code.