# How to deploy Web app in java

Tags: spring, webserver

I want to deploy a Java web app build in spring mvc to a server. I am using a MilesWeb server. After attempting to deploy the app on to the server I am getting the following exception logs with the description: "The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request". I need help to figure out what I am doing wrong.

```
exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet CMS threw exception
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:615)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:861)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:612)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:503)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
root cause

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Error loading class [com.cms.Controller.cmsController] for bean with name 'cmsController' defined in file [/opt/tomcat/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/classes/com/cms/Controller/cmsController.class]: problem with class file or dependent class; nested exception is java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/cms/Controller/cmsController : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0 (unable to load class com.cms.Controller.cmsController)
Related cause: org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Error loading class [com.cms.Controller.cmsController] for bean with name 'cmsController' defined in file [/opt/tomcat/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/classes/com/cms/Controller/cmsController.class]: problem with class file or dependent class; nested exception is java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/cms/Controller/cmsController : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0 (unable to load class com.cms.Controller.cmsController)
Related cause: org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Error loading class [com.cms.dao.RightsImpl] for bean with name 'rightsImpl' defined in file [/opt/tomcat/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/classes/com/cms/dao/RightsImpl.class]: problem with class file or dependent class; nested exception is java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/cms/dao/RightsImpl : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0 (unable to load class com.cms.dao.RightsImpl)
Related cause: org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Error loading class [com.cms.dao.UserroleImpl] for bean with name 'userroleImpl' defined in file [/opt/tomcat/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/classes/com/cms/dao/UserroleImpl.class]: problem with class file or dependent class; nested exception is java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/cms/dao/UserroleImpl : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0 (unable to load class com.cms.dao.UserroleImpl)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1578)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:775)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:861)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:541)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:668)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:634)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:682)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:553)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:494)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
    javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:212)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:615)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:861)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:612)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:503)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
root cause

org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Error loading class [com.cms.Controller.cmsController] for bean with name 'cmsController' defined in file [/opt/tomcat/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/classes/com/cms/Controller/cmsController.class]: problem with class file or dependent class; nested exception is java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/cms/Controller/cmsController : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0 (unable to load class com.cms.Controller.cmsController)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1360)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineTargetType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:628)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:597)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1450)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doGetBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:446)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:424)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:410)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBeanNamesForType(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1172)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.initHandlerMethods(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:199)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:184)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping.afterPropertiesSet(RequestMappingHandlerMapping.java:128)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1637)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:775)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:861)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:541)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:668)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:634)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:682)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:553)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:494)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
    javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:212)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:615)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:861)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:612)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:503)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
root cause

java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/cms/Controller/cmsController : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0 (unable to load class com.cms.Controller.cmsController)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:2858)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1159)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1647)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1526)
    org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:250)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinition.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanDefinition.java:394)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doResolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1402)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1349)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineTargetType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:628)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:597)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1450)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doGetBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:446)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:424)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:410)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBeanNamesForType(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1172)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.initHandlerMethods(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:199)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:184)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping.afterPropertiesSet(RequestMappingHandlerMapping.java:128)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1637)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:775)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:861)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:541)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:668)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:634)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:682)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:553)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:494)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
    javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:212)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:615)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:861)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:612)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:503)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/6.0.45 logs.
```

[you can check this link.after hitting submit i am getting above error](http://env-1801749.mj.milesweb.cloud/)

Comment: `nested exception is java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/cms/Controller/cmsController : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0 (unable to load class com.cms.Controller.cmsController)` This give a hint on the problem. And the title of the question is nowhere near the actual problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error occurred during deployment: Exception while deploying the app : UnsupportedClassVersionError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24652108/error-occurred-during-deployment-exception-while-deploying-the-app-unsupporte)

Answer (score 1):

The Java version of the server is too old. You must upgrade java on the server.

Answer (score 0):

It seems from the error "nested exception is java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError" that you have java mismatch. Either you are using the old tomcat and new spring or vice-versa. 
To resolve it, take the spring and tomcat version corresponding to your java version.

Comment: ok i will try this. thank you for your replay @ashishgupta_mca